# Как задать свой шаблон проекта в phpstorm?

Tags: веб-программирование, phpstorm

При создании нового проекта phpstorm предлагает выбрать его вид из предложенных, как добавить свой собственный шаблон для проекта?

Answer (score 1):

1. Открываете проект-шаблон.
2. Переходите в меню `Tools`.
3. Нажимаете `Save Project as Template`.
4. В появившемся окошке вводите название шаблона и его описание (последнее необязательно):

[image: PHPStorm - Save Project As Template]

5. Нажимаете `OK`.

При создании нового проекта ваш сохранённый шаблон буде фигурировать в общем списке внизу под заголовком `User-defined`:

[image: PHPStorm - New Project - User-defined]

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле этих настроек может быть вовсе недостаточно. Да, в шторме есть "создание шаблонов" и прочего. Но ни один из них, например, не умеют переносить **Scope**, **Color Files**,  древо цветов ну и ряд других настроек. И даже недавнее нововведение *"Save Project As Template/Сохранить проект как шаблон"*, не решает всех этих задач.

В общем, за несколько лет работы все свелось к банальному копированию папки проекта. Все настройки проекта лежат в папке *.idea*, вот вместе с ней и копируется проект.